# Need help with tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

When I print the tuple `(u'1S²')` I get the predicted output of `1S²`

However, when I print the tuple `(u'1S²',u'2S¹')` I get the output `(u'1S\xb2', u'2S\xb9')`.

Why is this? What can I do about this?
Also, how do I get the number of items in a tuple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `(u'1S²')` is not a `tuple`, it's a `unicode` value. A 1-tuple is written in Python this way: `(u'1S²',)`.

The `print value` statement prints a `str(value)` in fact. If you need to output several `unicode` strings, you should use something like this:

```
print u' '.join((u'1S²',u'2S¹'))
```

Though there might be issues with character encodings. If you know your console encoding, you may encode your `unicode` values to `str` manually:

```
ENCODING = 'utf-8'
print u' '.join((u'1S²',u'2S¹')).encode(ENCODING)
```

The number of iterms in tuples, lists, strings and other sequences can be obtained using `len` function.

Answer (score 2):

What platform and version of Python do you have? I don't see this behavior. I always get the `\x` escape sequences with Python 2.6:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 26 2010, 10:14:53)
>>> (u'1S²')
u'1S\xb2'
>>> (u'1S²',)
(u'1S\xb2',)
>>> (u'1S²',u'1S¹')
(u'1S\xb2', u'1S\xb9')
```

As a side note, `(u'1S²')` isn't a tuple, it's just a string with parentheses around it. You need a comma afterwards to create a single element tuple: `(u'1S²',)`.

As for the number of items, use `len`:

```
>>> len((u'1S²',u'1S¹'))
2
```

Comment: I see the same behaviour using v2.6.5 on Linux. +1 for the note on a single element tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`(u'1S²')` is not a tuple.
`(u'1S²',)` is a tuple containing u'1S²'.
`len((u'1S²',))` returns the length of the tuple, that is, 1.

also, when printing variables, beware there are 2 types of output :

- the programmer friendly string representation of the object : that is `repr(the_object)`
- the text representation of the object, mostly applicable for strings

if the second is not availlable, the first is used. unlike strings, tuples don't have a text representation, hence the programmer friendly representation is used to represent the tuple and its content.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example (u'1S²') isn't actually a tuple, it's a unicode string!

```
>>> t = (u'1S²')
>>> type(t)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print t
1S²
```

The comma is what makes it a tuple:

```
>>> t = (u'1S²',)
>>> type(t)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> print t
(u'1S\xb2',)
```

What's happening is when you *print* a tuple, you get the repr() of each of its components. To print the components, address them individually by index. You can get the length of a tuple with len():

```
>>> print t[0]
1S²
>>> len(t)
1
```