# Python regex issue from Kuchling's tutorial

Tags: python, regex

Referring to http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html section **Non-capturing and named groups**, I saw an example whose output is not obvious to me.

```
  >>> import re

  >>> m = re.match(r"([abc])+", "abc")
  >>> m.groups()

 ('c',)
```

Here I am not able to understand why the group(1) is 'c' and also why I see I dangling comma at the end. Can somebody help?

Comment: The trailing comma simply means it is a [1-tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680245/need-help-with-tuples-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the dangling comma, but your first group is `c`, because you let the group repeat itself by putting the `+` after the group, and not after the character group.

This way, the regex first matches `a`, which is assigned to group 1. Then, it matches `b`, which is also assigned to group 1. And at last, it matches `c`, assigned to group 1 and finishes; thus leaving your group 1 to be `c`.

If you write `([abc]+)`, your group 1 will be `abc`.